# What is the purpose of putting error message in URL [PHP]?

Tags: php, url

i was watching this tutorial https://youtu.be/LC9GaXkdxF8?t=2532 and at  42:15 the guy is putting PHP error in URL. But what is the purpose of it, if users don't look at urls and it's not user friendly, he should have displayed it in design. Now i don't really see any use of this, unless i'm misunderstanding something. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Later, when signup.php script will be requested by a browser, it can using that unfriendly error info, for example, to display it to user in user friendly manner.

## Updated

This script (foo.php) is demonstrating that:

```
<?php
$errors = array(
    'one' => "Error One is occured :(",
    'two' => "Error Two is occured :(",
    'three' => "Error Three is occured :("
);
if (!isset($_GET['error'])) {
    $data = "Signup is Success!!!";
} else {
    $err = $_GET['error'];
    $data = empty($errors[$err])? "Unknown Error is occured ...": $errors[$err];
}
echo $data;
```

That script can be requested as:

- /path/to/foo.php
- /path/to/foo.php?error=one
- /path/to/foo.php?error=two
- /path/to/foo.php?error=three
- /path/to/foo.php?error=four

Comment: Do you have an example or briefly exlain how you would do that? Because in his tutorial I don’t see him doing that so it was pointless for him to do that, or is that a good practice anyway?

Comment: I've updated the answer